# Minipage in a two column CV appears in the center than towards the left

Tags: horizontal-alignment, xetex, minipage, cv

I have used `minipage` to make a two column CV. The left column appears in the center of the page rather than the left side, while the right column starts below the left one and continues onto the next page. The code and resulting document are given. Please help

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hmargin=1.25cm, vmargin=0.7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{isodate}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\definecolor{headings}{HTML}{E74C3C}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{808B96} 
\definecolor{sepline}{HTML}{E74C3C}
\definecolor{main}{HTML}{17202A}
\setmainfont[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Reg.ttf}

%horizontal line seaparator
\newlength{\seplinewidth}
\newlength{\seplinesep}
\setlength{\seplinewidth}{0.5mm}
\setlength{\seplinesep}{2mm}
\newcommand*{\sepline}{%
  \par
  \vspace{\dimexpr\seplinesep+.5\parskip}%
  \cleaders\vbox{%
    \begingroup % because of color
      \color{sepline}%
      \hrule width\linewidth height\seplinewidth
    \endgroup
  }\vskip\seplinewidth
  \vspace{\dimexpr\seplinesep-.5\parskip}%
}

%underline
\setul{0.5ex}{0.2ex}
\setulcolor{sepline}

\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0.1cm}
\addtolength{\parskip}{-0.5mm}

%title formats
\newcommand{\sectiontitle}[1]{{\color{headings} \fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol.ttf} \Large \ul{#1}}}
\newcommand{\mainline}[1]{{\color{main} \fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol.ttf}#1}}
\newcommand{\institute}[1]{{\color{main} #1}}
\newcommand{\gpa}[3]{\color{gray} #1 : #2 | #3}
\newcommand{\guiduration}[2]{{
\color{main}  
\begin{tabularx}{0.6\textwidth}{X r}
(#1)  & [#2]
\end{tabularx}
}}

\newenvironment{tightemize}{\vspace{-\topsep}\begin{itemize}\itemsep1pt \parskip0pt \parsep0pt}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-\topsep}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\font\fb=''[cmr10]''
\setlength{\titlewidth}{454pt}

\centering{ 
{\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol.ttf} \Huge {\color{headings} Sumanth } \color{main}Umesh} \\
\color{gray}
Pre-Final Year B.Tech, Electrical Engineering\\
Indian Institute of Technology Jodhpur\\
sumanth.2@iitj.ac.in|+91-9632878570
}
\sepline
\vspace{-\topsep}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\linewidth}

\raggedright

%Education

\sectiontitle{Education}\\[2mm]
\mainline{B.Tech in Electrical Engineering}\\
\institute{Indian Institute of Technology, Jodhpur}\\
\gpa{GPA}{9.33/10.0}{Expected 2020}\\[2mm]

\mainline{Higher Secondary (KSEEB)}\\
\institute{VVS GJ PU College, Mysore}\\
\gpa{Percentage}{96.3\%}{2014-15}\\[2mm]

\mainline{Secondary (CBSE)}\\
\institute{Atomic Engery Central School, Mysore}\\
\gpa{GPA}{10.0/10.0}{2012-13}\newline\\

%Technical Skills

\sectiontitle{Technical Skills}\\[2mm]
\mainline{Programming Language}\\
C++ \textbullet{} MATLAB\\[0.5mm]
\mainline{Hardware Description Language}\\
Verilog\\[0.5mm]
\mainline{Simulation Software}\\
Simulink \textbullet{} SPICE\\[0.5mm]
\mainline{Micrcontroller Programming}\\
PIC \textbullet{} Arduino \textbullet{} Embedded C\newline\\

%Coursework

\sectiontitle{Coursework}\\[2mm]
Computer Architecture\\
Microprocessors and Microcontrollers \\
Digital Logic and Design \\
Physics of Semiconductor Devices \\
Analog Electronics \\
Communication Systems \\
Signals and Systems \\
Electromagnetic Theory \\
Circuit Theory \\
Probability, Statistics and Random Processes \\
Complex Analysis and Differential Equation \\
Linear Algerbra and Calculus\\

\end{minipage}%

\hfill

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}

\sectiontitle{Projects}\\[2mm]
\mainline{Automated Farm Security System}\\
\guiduration{Self-Project}{Sep 2017 - Mar 2018}


\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]`

Comment: You do not use `\centering{...}`, but instead `{\centering ...}`, or better yet `\begin{center} ... \end{center}`. This should fix your problem. :-) I do not have your font family `Lato` to produce any output though.